# Http response at 400 or 500 level

Tags: javascript, django, nuxt.js, grpc, envoyproxy

I'm novice in gRPC. My program is written with ‍‍`nuxtjs` and is a simple `login page` that receives the `username` and `password` and sends it to the server using gRPC.
Everything is fine when I submit a request with [BloomRPC](https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc). But when using the browser, the request is not sent to the server.

My `auth` class is as follow:

```
// auth.js

export default class {
  constructor(vars) {
    this.tokenKey = vars.tokenKey
    this.proto = vars.proto
    this.client = new vars.proto.AuthenticationClient('http://127.0.0.1:50051', null, null)
  }

  async loginRequest(user) {
    const request = new this.proto.LoginRequest()
    request.setUsername(user.username.trim().toLowerCase())
    request.setPassword(user.password.trim()) 
    return await this.client.login(request, {})    
  } 
}
```

This error is shown when requesting to the server with the browser, whether the server is up or not.

```
net ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
message: 'Http response at 400 or 500 level'
...
```

***Chrome Screenshot:***
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

**Do I have to do a specific configuration?**

*I just want a hint for configuring.*

### **UPDATE:**

[This link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/769#issuecomment-606722616) says that you should use Envoy. But why do we need it? And how do I configure it?

***BloomRPC screenshot:***

As you can see on the right side of the image, the answer is returned correctly.
[image: bloomrpc screenshot]

Comment: Is `nuxt` actually running and listening 5005 port? Does it log something?

Comment: @Anton Nuxt is running on 3000 port and  as you can see in the code, the request is sent to port 50051, where the server is listening.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But does gRPC server log something?

Comment: You can try `curl -v http://127.0.01:5005` to check that port actually listening.

Comment: @Anton No. Does not record any logs. This is probably because the request will not be sent to the server.

Comment: It seems like `127.0.0.1:5005` actually not listening (also, listening `localhost` is not the same as listening `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: @Anton Exactly. Adequate configuration to connect to the server should probably be done.

Comment: Can you show screenshots of BloomRPC, with success queries?

Comment: @Anton Thanks for continuing to help. I am sending now.

Comment: @Saeed I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322610/is-there-a-possibility-to-use-grpc-in-nuxt-js). The only answer said that you have to use [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web).

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Thanks. I've seen this answer before. The upvoted question and answer was done by me. I'm using [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) but it looks like it has configurations that I do not know how it is. I need to read more.

Comment: @Saeed well if you find a solution add an answer here. Could be very usefull!

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito The problem was that the requests did not reach the server and I needed a proxy to send the requests from the client to the server. Please see my answer.

Comment: you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70637968/5767110) about configuring the envoy proxy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Where was the problem?

The problem is that requests do not reach the server. So it does not matter if the server is up or down.

### > Short Answer:

I needed a proxy to receive requests from the server. So I used ‍[envoy proxy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy). In this way, [nginx](https://github.com/nginx/nginx) received the request from the browser and then sent it to a port (for example 5000). On the other hand, `envoy` listens to port 5000 and then sends the request to the server running on port 50051.

*This is how I designed the tracking of a `gRPC` connection.*

[image: gRPC traking a request]

---

### > Long Answer:

**1.** Generate html/css/js file with building `nuxt` project.
I put my website files in the `root/site‍` folder.

**2. `envoy` config:**
I config `envoy.yaml` file as follows according to what the [documentions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld/envoy.yaml) [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) said.

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 5000 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              config:
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route:
                            cluster: sample_cluster
                            max_grpc_timeout: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
    - name: sample_cluster
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 50051 }}]
```

This yaml file has two parts `listeners` and `clusters`. In the first part(`listeners`), we specify which port and address for listening(*For example, here is address 0.0.0.0 and port 5000*), and in the second part(`clusters`), we tell it where to send the requests(*here is address 0.0.0.0 and port 50051*). To use this file, we give it to [Docker](https://docker.com). So I create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

```
# Dockerfile
FROM envoyproxy/envoy:v1.14.3
COPY ./envoy.yaml /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
EXPOSE 5000
CMD /usr/local/bin/envoy -c /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```

To build the container, I use the following commands inside `Dockerfile` folder and then run it.

```
docker build -t my-grpc-container:1.0.0 .
docker run -d --net=host my-grpc-container:1.0.0
```

> By executing the above commands, `envoy` is up and listens to port
> 5000 and sends requests to port 500051.

*For more information about `envoy` read [this](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/envoy-and-grpc-web-a-fresh-new-alternative-to-rest-6504ce7eb880) nice blog:*

> **The role of Envoy:**
>
> Envoy translates the HTTP/1.1 calls produced by the client into HTTP/2 calls that can be handled by those services
> (gRPC uses HTTP/2 for transport).

**3. `nginx` config:**

I went to the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` folder and open `default` file and set the path of my website files(see section 1) as follows:

```
# server block
root /root/site;
```

Then told `nginx` that if a request in the `url` started with `/rpc/`, send it to 5000 port(*where `envoy` is listening*):

```
# server block
location /rpc/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }
```

Then I restart `nginx`:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

> By doing this part, `nginx` is up and send requests that start with
> `/rpc/` to port 5000, where `envoy` is ready to receive.

---

**In summary:**

1. The server is running on port 50051.
2. ‍`nginx` sends requests to port 5000.
3. `envoy`, as an interface between the `server` and `nginx`, receives
   requests from port 5000 and sends them to port 50051.

Done

Comment: Thank you so much @Saeed, clear and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to chrome screenshot you trying to access to `5005` port in JS, but according to BloomRPC, screenshot your service listening `50051`.

Comment: Please see the new screenshot. No change.

Comment: @Saeed I suggest you try to change port, and make sure you use same host for your app and server (i.e. both 127.0.0.1 or both localhost)

Comment: Also, is this your issue? - https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/1175

Comment: The problem was that the requests did not reach the server. Please see my answer. I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

A very well written [article](https://nuvalence.io/insights/lessons-learned-investigating-goaways-in-grpc-apis/) about strange GoAway 503 occurrences with gRPC in combination with a proxy (in that case an NGINX) helped me understand more about possible ssl hickups.

Also I learned that gRPC came up with automatic Retry Mechanisms from [v.1.41.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases?page=5) - I am using gRPC in the Java world here.