# React + gRPC don't reach envoy container

Tags: reactjs, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I was trying to build a very basic web page in React that would send gRPC request to a backend written in Rust.

I followed these guides:

https://daily.dev/blog/build-a-chat-app-using-grpc-and-reactjs

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld

However, I cannot get the gRPC request to reach the envoy proxy in the docker container (envoy is the only component running inside a container so far).

This is my proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package Base;

service Hello {
    rpc HelloWorld(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
}

message HelloRequest {}
message HelloResponse {
    string message = 1;
}
```

This is my App.js file (basically as it gets created by the react bootstrapper, I just added the function and the button)

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { HelloClient } from './base_grpc_web_pb';
import { HelloRequest } from './base_pb';

const client = new HelloClient("http://" + window.location.hostname + ":8080", null, null);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <button
        onClick={sendRequest}
        style={{
          padding: "7px 38px",
          fontSize: "1.2em",
          boxSizing: "content-box",
          borderRadius: "4px",
        }}
      >
        Join
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function sendRequest() {
  const request = new HelloRequest();
  
  console.log("CLICK");

  client.helloWorld(request, {}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.log("BBBBB error", err);
    console.log("AAAAA RESPONSE", response.getMessage());
  });
}


export default App;
```

This is my envoy configuration (I am on Ubuntu 22.04, so no need to override the address with `host.docker.internal`):

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: proxy
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route:
                            cluster: hellors
                            timeout: 0s
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: hellors
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      # win/mac hosts: Use address: host.docker.internal instead of address: localhost in the line below
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 0.0.0.0
                      port_value: 9090
```

Dockerfile for envoy:

```
FROM envoyproxy/envoy-dev:latest
COPY envoy.yaml /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
RUN chmod go+r /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```

In the console, after I click the button I get this error message:

```
http://localhost:8080/Base.Hello/HelloWorld [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 5ms]
```

Followed by

```
message: "Http response at 400 or 500 level", [...]
```

If I try to curl the port it seems like it isn't listening:

```
>$ curl -v http://localhost:8080
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 145
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Thu, 28 Apr 2022 16:03:55 GMT
< server: envoy
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111
```

At this point I am quite stuck, all the configuration files seem ok, yet I still can't reach the envoy proxy. Any suggestions?

I have stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393465/http-response-at-400-or-500-level) that suggests to use nginx, however I don't understand why that would be needed, especially since the gRPC examples I was looking at don't use it.

Comment: I've reproduced your example with a working gRPC server and got no error. However, after killing the gRPC service (`hellors`), I received your error `Http response at 400 or 500 level`. So my guess is that the gRPC service is not called/accessible. In your question, you said that Envoy is running in a Docker container. However, the cluster `hellors` in your Envoy config points to `0.0.0.0:9090`. I think your `hellors` is not reachable because Envoy is isolated in a Docker network. You may want to try running Envoy in your host network (`--net=host`).

Comment: Also, if you want to take a look at a full working example with gRPC-web and Envoy, you can find something interesting here: https://github.com/norbjd/grpc-web-nginx-envoy/tree/without-nginx. The gRPC server is in Node.JS, but you got the idea.

Comment: @norbjd that actually worked, thanks a lot. I had tried it before without luck but I probably messed up some other configuration. If you reply properly I will award the tick for correct response and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `Http response at 400 or 500 level` is probably caused by the fact that your gRPC service is not reachable from Envoy.

You said that Envoy is running in a Docker container. If so, the cluster `hellors` in your Envoy config:

```yaml
clusters:
- name: hellors
  load_assignment:
    endpoints:
    - lb_endpoints:
      - endpoint:
          address:
            socket_address:
              address: 0.0.0.0
              port_value: 9090
```

cannot be reached because you specify the address `0.0.0.0`. Docker containers use their own networks, so inside that network, the `0.0.0.0:9090` is not defined, because your gRPC service is running on your host.

You may want to try running Envoy in your host network (--net=host).

Or if your gRPC service can be containerized, you can run Envoy **and** the gRPC service in the same Docker network.